# Looking for an Abstract Typescript Logging Framework

Tags: typescript, logging, frameworks, libraries

I have been searching for a library that abstracts logging frameworks like SLF4J in Typescript but have not been able to find one. There are several logging frameworks like Bunyan, Winston, Pino, etc. But I haven't found something similar to SLF4J that can abstract these frameworks through a generic Logger interface for Typescript. Could you provide some links or resources that provide this kind of abstraction? Preferably libraries that are maintained.